# MarkLogic Sparql insert after clear/drop graph

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, sjs

From Query Console after clear/drop the graph. Trying to insert triples from Java using ResourceManager and SJS. It does not getting inserted, but after few (say 5 min) minutes if we try again using java it gets inserted.

Comment: Are you saying that you drop the graph in Query Console, and then run a separate Java process to insert, and that doesn't work unless you wait a few minutes? What's the role of SJS (what is that code doing)?

Comment: In SJS using sem.sparqlUpdate inserting new triples from other collection.

Comment: Can you share your code and some more details?

Comment: I've seen lags like this  -- the delay between insert and indexing.  It would help to know what version you're on -- this has probably been addressed in the fixes leading up to 8.0-4 (which will be out soon).

Comment: version is 8.0-1. Thanks grechaw.

Comment: 8.0-4 has been released -- could you tell us whether the same problem occurs with that version?